# how to fix scilab Undefined variable error problem?

Tags: scilab

Using scilab for the first time and I do not know how to fix it. I want to convert RGB image to grayscale.  What to do?

[image: awefew]

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.

Comment: Hi Riazul! Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please include your relevant code and the exact error? Just having an image makes it harder for people to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `imread()` function doesn't exist natively in Scilab (are you trying to port a Matlab code?). It does exist, however, as part of the [SIP (Scilab Image Processing) toolbox](http://siptoolbox.sourceforge.net/doc/sip-0.7.0-reference/section_6f36af5cf908b1ede84d360e67b7d40c.html) which can be downloaded and installed using **ATOMS** (Scilab's Toolbox Manager). You can find ATOMS under the "Applications>ATOMS" menu in the Scilab console.

SIP also comes with the `im2gray()` function which essentially does what you want. After having installed and loaded SIP in Atoms, try:

```
// import RGB jpeg pic
RGBpic = imread("rgb.jpg");
// convert to grayscale
GSpic = im2gray(RGBpic);
// create new figure window and display grayscale pic  
scf(0);clf();
imshow(GSpic);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install "Image Processing and Computer Vision Toolbox".

Step 1: Go in Main Categories.
Step 2 : Under The ATOMS, You will see multiple options. You should just select Image Processing.
Step 3: Then You will there are two options just select and download
"Image Processing and Computer Vision Toolbox".

I am sure your problem will resolve 100%.